# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address

Tags: dyld

I run a Matlab script that called functions from Freesurfer and FieldTrip softwares, and I systematically get this error message :

> adding the FreeSurfer environment dyld: lazy symbol binding failed:
>   Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/freesurfer/bin/../lib/gcc/lib/libgomp.1.dylib   Expected
>   in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/freesurfer/bin/../lib/gcc/lib/libgomp.1.dylib   Expected
>   in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

From the others' questions, I tried to install Xcode and GCC, but it still does not work. I saw that a possibility is to turn off my mac's System Integrity Protection, but it is not recommended... So I'd like to know if there is another solution ?

Thank you !

Comment: After upgrading the version of the org.deeplearning4j from 1.0.0-beta5 to 1.0.0-beta6 it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I come across similar problem when calling freeview.
It disappears after restart a session.
And it appears after I change the SUBJECTS_DIR variable.